# Camel Quarkus ClassNotFoundException: HttpOperationFailedException

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I have a Quarkus app that uses Apache-Camel and runs fine locally.
When I build it and try to run the docker container then I get the following error:

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException
at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.CamelQuarkusClassResolver.resolveMandatoryClass(CamelQuarkusClassResolver.java:68)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.errorhandler.ErrorHandlerReifier.createExceptionClasses(ErrorHandlerReifier.java:197)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.errorhandler.ErrorHandlerReifier.addExceptionPolicy(ErrorHandlerReifier.java:177)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.errorhandler.ErrorHandlerReifier.configure(ErrorHandlerReifier.java:220)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.errorhandler.DefaultErrorHandlerReifier.createErrorHandler(DefaultErrorHandlerReifier.java:53)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelReifierFactory.createErrorHandler(DefaultModelReifierFactory.java:65)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.errorhandler.ErrorHandlerRefReifier.createErrorHandler(ErrorHandlerRefReifier.java:36)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelReifierFactory.createErrorHandler(DefaultModelReifierFactory.java:65)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.wrapInErrorHandler(ProcessorReifier.java:751)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.wrapChannelInErrorHandler(ProcessorReifier.java:732)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.wrapChannel(ProcessorReifier.java:711)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.wrapChannel(ProcessorReifier.java:617)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.wrapProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:613)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.makeProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:860)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.addRoutes(ProcessorReifier.java:585)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:236)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:74)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelReifierFactory.createRoute(DefaultModelReifierFactory.java:49)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:887)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.addRouteDefinitions(DefaultModel.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:344)
at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.populateRoutes(RouteBuilder.java:676)
at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.addRoutesToCamelContext(RouteBuilder.java:529)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.addRoutes(AbstractCamelContext.java:1175)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notifyObservers(EventImpl.java:323)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:305)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:73)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.fireLifecycleEvent(ArcRecorder.java:130)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:99)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:103)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
```

My gradle dependencies are

```
dependencies {
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-container-image-docker'
implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:quarkus-camel-bom:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml'

implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-jwt'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-metrics'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build'

implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'

implementation 'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-file'
implementation 'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-core'
implementation 'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-base64'
implementation 'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-ahc'
implementation 'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-jackson'
implementation 'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-ftp'
implementation 'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-rest'
implementation 'org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-http'

implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.1'

testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
```

}

When I run it with "quarkus dev" in IntelliJ Terminal I have no problems. Do I try to run the container I get the error. Why does it happen? I have no clue how to solve it.

Edit:

Where the HttpException ist handled:

```
 onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
            .process(new HttpExceptionHandler())
            .maximumRedeliveries(5)
            .redeliveryDelay(1000L)
            .backOffMultiplier(2)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
            .handled(true)
            .stop();
```

The Handler itself:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.component.file.FileConstants;
import org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class HttpExceptionHandler implements org.apache.camel.Processor {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HttpExceptionHandler.class);

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) {
    HttpOperationFailedException failedException = exchange.getProperty(
            Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT,
            HttpOperationFailedException.class);

    ...

}
```

}

Comment: do you use native image

Comment: yes, I do use native image.

Comment: Can u try with jvm image if this fix  We can open issue in github

Comment: I ran 

./gradlew build -x test -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.containerBuild=true -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=6g --warning-mode all --stacktrace

if I then try to run via the build/*-runner file I get the same error as above. 
If I use the jar under build/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar I don't receive the error

Comment: Do you use HttpOperationFailedException with an OnException clause in your routes?

Comment: Yes, I have a custom handler for it. 
I added it to the main question for readability reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `onException` in your routes, the class that you define needs to be registered for reflection in order for it to work in native mode.

So if you have `.onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)`, then `HttpOperationFailedException` needs to be registered for reflection. For example:

```
@RegisterForReflection(targets = HttpOperationFailedException.class)
public class Routes extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() {
        // Route configuration goes here
    }
}
```

There's some more information in the Camel Quarkus user guide about this:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/2.11.x/user-guide/native-mode.html#using-onexception-clause-in-native-mode

I opened an issue to improve things for the future so that `HttpOperationFailedException` does not need to be manually registered.

https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/issues/3971